# Error in opening R packages

Tags: r, dll, package

I have installed some packages on R Studio on my laptop, and I am having some issues opening them. When I try

```
require(ggplot)
```

I get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/marky/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any clue to what is going on? It appears that Rcpp has something to do with converting C++ to R. When I go to the directory, I see it (although the size is 0KB). I also get this [error on the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AuxQ.png)

Comment: Did you mean `require(ggplot2)`? What happens if you try re-installing it with `install.packages("ggplot2")`?

Comment: `Rcpp/libs/x64` -- it looks like you're trying to use 64-bit R/R packages on a 32-bit machine?